# Turning a Vec<Rc<RefCell<T>>> into a &[&mut T]

Tags: rust, lifetime

I've got a vector of reference-counted `RefCell`s and want to pass a `Vec` of (`mut`) references into the `RefCell`s into a function.  The references shouldn't need to outlive the function call.

It seems like it should be possible (with just one, something like `&*x.borrow_mut()` is ok).  I tried to keep intermediate vectors of `RefMut` and `&mut` to control the lifetimes, but I haven't yet worked out a way to get it to work:

```
use std::cell::{RefCell,RefMut};
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait SomeTrait {}

struct Wrapper<'a> {
    pub r: &'a mut SomeTrait,
}

fn foo(_: &[Wrapper]) {}

fn main() {
    let mut v1: Vec<Rc<RefCell<SomeTrait>>> = unimplemented!();

    let mut v_rm: Vec<RefMut<_>> = v1.iter_mut().map(|r| r.borrow_mut()).collect();
    let mut v_wrapper: Vec<Wrapper> = v_rm.iter_mut().map(|ref mut rm| Wrapper{ r: &mut ***rm }).collect();
    foo(&v_wrapper[..]);
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b79b6ca328c19aebbf5dca39e70bae03&version=stable&backtrace=0))

There's clearly a lifetime issue:

```
rustc 1.11.0 (9b21dcd6a 2016-08-15)
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:17:60
   |>
17 |>     let mut v_wrapper: Vec<Wrapper> = v_rm.iter_mut().map(|ref mut rm| Wrapper{ r: &mut ***rm }).collect();
   |>                                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
note: reference must be valid for the block suffix following statement 2 at 17:107...
  --> <anon>:17:108
   |>
17 |>     let mut v_wrapper: Vec<Wrapper> = v_rm.iter_mut().map(|ref mut rm| Wrapper{ r: &mut ***rm }).collect();
   |>                                                                                                            ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 17:71
  --> <anon>:17:72
   |>
17 |>     let mut v_wrapper: Vec<Wrapper> = v_rm.iter_mut().map(|ref mut rm| Wrapper{ r: &mut ***rm }).collect();
   |>                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I do control `foo` so can alter its API to make things easier, but it's in a different module/crate and I don't really want it to need to know that I keep my `SomeTrait` objects in an `Rc<RefCell<_>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I agree with @delnan that you should switch to an iterator-based interface if you can.

Most of this code is just fine, and after changing `foo` and `Wrapper` to be a bit more flexible, I was able to tweak the rest and get it to compile:

```
use std::cell::{RefCell,RefMut};
use std::vec::Vec;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait SomeTrait {}

struct Wrapper<'a, 'b> where 'b: 'a {
    pub r: &'a mut (SomeTrait + 'b),
}

fn foo<'a, 'b>(_: &'a mut [Wrapper<'a, 'b>]) where 'b: 'a {}

fn main() {
    let mut v1: Vec<Rc<RefCell<SomeTrait>>> = unimplemented!();

    let mut v_rm: Vec<RefMut<_>> = v1.iter_mut().map(|r| r.borrow_mut()).collect();
    let mut v_wrapper: Vec<Wrapper> = v_rm.iter_mut().map(|mut rm| Wrapper{ r: &mut **rm }).collect();
    foo(&mut v_wrapper[..]);
}
```

The key thing to understand here is that *every* trait object type has an implicit lifetime stapled to it, because an impl may contain references. There's no such type as `SomeTrait`, only `SomeTrait + 'a` or `SomeTrait + 'b` or `SomeTrait + 'static`.

The problem in your code was a mismatch between two things Rust inferred.

- Where you wrote `Rc<RefCell<SomeTrait>>`, Rust assumed you meant `Rc<RefCell<SomeTrait + 'static>>`.
- Where you wrote `fn foo(_: &[Wrapper]) {}`, different rules applied, and Rust assumed you meant `fn foo<'a>(_: &'a [Wrapper<'a> + 'a])`.

D'oh. Under those assumptions, the puzzle indeed has no solutions, and that's why I had to loosen things up.

If you don't want that `'b` lifetime parameter, you can ditch it and just change `'b` to `'static` in the one place where it's used (on the type of `Wrapper::r`). That's less flexible: you'll be limited to `SomeTrait` impls that have static lifetime.

Comment: That's useful, thanks. I think I get the rules for elided lifetimes in function signatures (at least sometimes). Where is the inferred `'static` on the `Rc<RefCell<SomeTrait>>` described/documented?

Comment: I think I've found it: [RFC 599](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0599-default-object-bound.md)

Comment: ...amended by [RFC 1156](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1156-adjust-default-object-bounds.md)

Answer (score 3):

While it is certainly possible to write code that starts with a `Vec<RefMut<T>>` and creates a `Vec<&mut T>` from that ([generic example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8b807709d046f550d8dfd290606f3d60&version=stable&backtrace=0)), I would suggest that you change the signature of `foo`. Many algorithms do not need the random access provided by slices, and if the function could accept an iterator instead of a slice, you wouldn't need to create *two* whole additional `Vec`s, aside from the calling function becoming simpler. I'm thinking of a signature like this

```
fn foo<I, R>(widgets: I)
    where I: IntoIterator<Item=R>,
          R: DerefMut<Target=SomeTrait>
{
    for widget in widgets {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then all you need is producing an iterator that yields `RefMut`'s, which is easily accomplished with `v1.iter_mut().map(|x| x.borrow_mut())`. [Here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8b4b123afce78b1f58f7bc5758e2e367&version=stable&backtrace=0) an example.

Comment: Does your `wrangle_mut_refs` example actually work starting from a `Vec<Rc<RefCell<T>>>`?  It's close to what I had, and still doesn't seem to resolve the lifetime issues my code has.

Comment: The more generic version does look like an improvement, except that `foo` in this case needs to iterate more than once, so relying on `IntoIterator` probably doesn't work.  However, maybe using `DerefMut` would make it possible to pass in a slice of `RefMut`.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson `wrangle_mut_refs` works from `Vec<RefMut<T>>`, but in the question you already successfully creates that from the `Vec<Rc<RefCell<T>>>`.

Comment: I'm not sure that my `Vec<RefMut<T>>` is necessarily usable though.  :-(  I tried to make use of your `wrangle_mut_refs` but without success: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b79b6ca328c19aebbf5dca39e70bae03&version=stable&backtrace=0)  The lifetime errors now go back to the `v1` not living long enough.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson The problematic part is the `ref mut` pattern -- unsurprisingly, I might add, since that's the main difference between the code in the question and `wrangle_mut_refs` ;-) This compiles: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fd3d624cfd8b6b3a1717da3e963f83ac&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: Aha! Yeah, I guess the "***" was a clue that something probably wasn't quite right. :-)